# Add delay to network interface at boot

Tags: ubuntu, networking, boot, vpn, delay

I'm currently working on a Raspberry Pi project, running Ubuntu Mate 32 bit,
The RPi is going to be at sea and connects to the internet via a 4G router. Via the VPN network, it sends data to another computer on land which is running an HMI. Also a VNC connection is run via the VPN connection.

At boot, it automatically connects to a VPN server.

My problem is (I think) that when power is applied to the system and the RPi and router boots simultaneously, the RPi boots up first and tried to connect via the network interface, but fails to do so, since the router is not yet booted up.

The RPi continually tries to connect until the router is finally up and running. However, this process does something to the VPN connection and I'm not able to receive data from the RPi on the VPN network, even though both machines are connected to the VPN network.

If I then reboot the RPi and connect with the router up and running, it works fine and I can receive data.

As a solution, I want to add a 30 second delay to the network interface trying to connect, giving the router time to boot properly.

How can I do this? Or do anyone have a better suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I have found a solution which is acceptable, but not the best.

Add a boot_delay=60 to /boot/config.txt

It adds a 1 minute delay to the boot process and allows the router to boot first.

Answer (score 1):

In you systemd service you can configure to start VPN after the connection is ok. The solution is change the `After` directive on unit file. For example `sshd` service is on this file `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sshd.service` and the `After` option force service to start after network:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenSSH Daemon
Wants=sshdgenkeys.service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sshd -D
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So you have to change `After` for VPN service like `vpn.service`